# how to Sending sms in android

Tags: java, android, sms

I am developing an application using sms, my requirement is 1) send sms with static values 2)whenever we click on edit button we can change values and send sms , I can do both of them successfully but my third requirement is to send sms only when click on edit and change values click on submit buttons, without change value I do not want send sms. I want when click on edit button then only send sms, i tried with if(editBtn.isSelected) but it is not working. please tell any solution

my code is

xml file

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
  android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
  android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
  android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
  tools:context=".MainActivity"
  android:orientation="vertical" >

  <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:id="@+id/editBtn"
       android:text="EDIT"
       android:textColor="#00FF00"
       android:onClick="editListener"/>
  <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:orientation="horizontal">
   <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:text="NUMBER"
             android:textSize="20dip"/>
   <EditText android:layout_width="150dip"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:id="@+id/numberEdit"
             android:text="8989897979"
             android:clickable="false" 
             android:cursorVisible="false" 
             android:focusable="false" 
             android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
             />
  </LinearLayout>
  <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:orientation="horizontal">
   <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:text="MESSAGE"
             android:textSize="20dip"/>
   <EditText android:layout_width="150dip"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:id="@+id/messageEdit"
             android:text="HAI HOW R U"
             android:clickable="false" 
             android:cursorVisible="false" 
             android:focusable="false" 
             android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
             />

   </LinearLayout>
    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:id="@+id/subBtn"
           android:text="SUBMIT"/>
  </LinearLayout>
```

Activty

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private EditText contactEdit;
private EditText messageEdit;
private Button  submitBtn;
private Button  editBtn;

String contact;
String message;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    contactEdit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.numberEdit);
    messageEdit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.messageEdit);
    submitBtn   = (Button)findViewById(R.id.subBtn);
    editBtn     = (Button)findViewById(R.id.editBtn);

    if(editBtn.isSelected()){
    submitBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            contact = contactEdit.getText().toString();
            message = messageEdit.getText().toString();

            try{
                SmsManager manger = SmsManager.getDefault();

                manger.sendTextMessage(contact, null, message, null, 
                                    null);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS SENT", 
                              100).show();
            }
            catch(Exception e){

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS NOT          
                            SEND", 100).show();
                e.printStackTrace();

            }

        }
    });
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "NOT EDITED", 100).show();
    }
    editBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            changeEdit();

        }
    });
}


private void changeEdit(){
    contactEdit.setClickable(true);
    contactEdit.setCursorVisible(true);
    contactEdit.setFocusable(true);
    contactEdit.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    messageEdit.setClickable(true);
    messageEdit.setCursorVisible(true);
    messageEdit.setFocusable(true);
    messageEdit.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
}

 }
```

Comment: you can take a flag variable to check whether edit is clicked or not.

Comment: and you can preserve values, to later make sure on *submit*, if the values have actually been changed or not.

Comment: i am new in android i dont know how to take fag variableplease tell me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use OnTouchListener for the edittext

sample,

```
  editBtn.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                           changeEdit();

            return true;
        }
    });
```

if its not working

Create a boolean variable Globally and make it true if u touched onto the edittext,

//In grobal

```
 boolean e_clicked = false;
```

//Inside the Edittext onTouchListener

```
 e_clicked=true;
```

and check

```
 if(e_clicked)
 {
 // your sms send action
 }
```

Comment: He mentioned, "without changes, I do not want to send msg". What if i touch *Edit* button, and don't change values? Values need to be preserved to later check, i guess.

Comment: @Zeeshan if your is true, add TextWatcher Listener for Edittext

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
     public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent intent=new Intent(context,Service.class);
    //get lat/lng and pass it or get from service if u want
    intent.putExtra("lat","lat");
    intent.putExtra("lon","lng");
    context.startService(intent);

}  
    }

    public void SetAlarm(Context context) {

        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent i = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);
         Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

           calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());

           calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 10);
           am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(),
                calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pi);
    }
```